# How to combine Materialise Autocomplete with Google Places Autocomplete?

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, materialize, phonegap

How to combine [in built autocomplete of materialize](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete) with the [Google Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)?

Without the map of course.

I am buiilding a PhoneGap based mobile app for Android and iOS. The problem is that the default interface of Google Places API is not very user friendly in some devices. Is there a way to produce the suggestion in the inbuilt autocomplete of materialize framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the dropdown via css. You can find more information about that [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete)